# detecting insert-normal mode

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode, statusline

I notice that when in insert, pressing `<C-o>` will take me to normal mode, but once I finish pressing a sequence of keys, I get taken back to insert mode. I find this very useful, but I want a way of programatically detecting this, so I can reflect the difference in my statusline. The help page for `mode()` only mentions normal mode, whereas I can see with `set showmode`, vim displays `-- (insert) --` instead of `-- INSERT --` so clearly it differentiates between the two to some extent.

Note; I have `set noshowmode` set because I want to have **just** my statusline display the mode. I am looking for a way to do this **without** using `showmode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The help page for mode() only mentions normal mode

That's not true. The help page (`:h mode()`) is quite complete. You have to supply an optional argument for the `mode()` function.

```
let s:mode = mode(1)
if s:mode[0] ==# 'n'
    if s:mode[1] ==# 'i'
        " normal using i_CTRL-O
    elseif s:mode[1] ==# 'o'
        " normal Operator-pending
    else
        " just normal
    endif
endif
```

If `:h mode()` page does not mention `niI`, `niR` etc. then this version of Vim does not support this feature and should be updated first.

Comment: when I do this from insert-normal it doesn't seem to work. I saw the part about the optional non-zero argument, but it doesn't seem to behave that way on my machine.

Comment: as in, mode(1) in insert-normal just returns 'n' rather than 'ni'

Comment: @myc3lium That's strange. If I do in insert mode `<C-O>:echo mode(1)` it prints `niI` just as expected.

Comment: would the version of vim have anything to do with it? If returning 'ni' was introduced later on as an extension to `mode`'s  behaviour... I'm using vim 7.4, so.

Comment: @myc3lium You should read `mode()` help page as it is in your version of Vim.

Comment: Just read the help page, it doesn't mention the behaviour you specified. The optional argument is there, but none of the return values it lists are prefixed with 'n' (e.g. 'ni'). It seems the only multi-character values it returns in my version of vim are 'cv', 'rm' etc.

Comment: @myc3lium So then you have to update Vim.

Comment: I'm just going to assume this isn't supported in my version. Should I edit my original question and say as much? I want to mark your answer as accepted, because it should work (just not for me), but I'm not sure whether that's considered appropriate.

Comment: @myc3lium I suppose it's enough if I mention it in my answer.